# MobileFirst Java Adapter: returning POJO ignores json annotations

Tags: java, json, jackson, mobilefirst-adapters

when (RESTful) Java adapter returns a POJO class as result (for example:

```
public class MyBean {
public int id;
private String name;

@JsonGetter("name")
public String getTheName() {
    return name;
}}
```

}

)
The MFP server ignores the `@JsonGetter` or many other Jackson annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason was the json annotation version I used.
MobileFirst uses jackson mapper v2.5.4 
while I tried to import the older `org.codehaus....JsonGetter` instead of newer `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonGetter` inside the Java adapter code.
The real issue is that there is no warning or errors if you bring non-matching jackson library.